# How to get LowCodeUnit to create my yml file?

Tags: yaml, github-actions, web-hosting

I was reading the docs for hosting my GitHub repo via LowCodeUnit and saw that the yml file was supposed to be generated for me when I set up a source control. The problem is that when I save that source control nothing happens, no github actions kick off and yml file is not created. Is there a way to force it to be generated?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a problem with the GitHub Oauth. If you go to your github settings, click on applications and go to the "Authorized OAuth Apps" tab and then revoke access to Fathym LowCodeUnit. Then navigate back to LowCodeUnit, connect your GitHub account again and then make a new source control you should see that yml file will be created for you.